# How to Achieve Better Contrast with ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I'm trying to create a plot of values of following structure and would like to visualize its vector length as a function of colour.

```
{{0.993039, 0.0135508, 1.8244}, {0.993039, 0.0134245, 
  1.8244}, {0.663126, 0.0134361, 1.79733}, {0.497758, 0.0146057, 
  1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.014195, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.014113, 
  1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0140746, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0139925, 
  1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0139491, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0139141, 
  1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0138091, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.013683, 
  1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.01359, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0135753, 
  1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0135056, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0134964, 
  1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0147068, 1.76709}, {0.497758, 0.0144276, 
  1.76709}, {0.497758, 0.0144274, 1.76709}, {0.497758, 0.014408, 
  1.76709}, {0.497758, 0.0135405, 1.76709}, {0.497758, 0.0142663, 
  1.76083}, {0.497758, 0.0141228, 1.76083}, {0.497758, 0.0140877, 
  1.76083}, {0.398405, 0.0148334, 1.74231}, {0.398405, 0.0145646, 
  1.74231}, {0.398405, 0.0139414, 1.74231}, {0.398405, 0.0149173, 
  1.73337}, {0.332114, 0.0151498, 1.72431}, {0.332114, 0.0145874, 
  1.72431}}
```

To achieve decent colour contrast I've hard to hard code in a `Rescale` step which I can hardly imagine is best practice.

```
cf[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{var},
  var = Rescale[EuclideanDistance[{0, 0, 0}, {x, y, z}], {1.03, 1.31}];
  ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][var]
  ]
viewFitness[data_] := Module[{var},
  ListPointPlot3D[data,
   ImageSize -> Large,
   ColorFunction -> cf,
   Axes -> True
   ]
  ]
```

As I scale up the project, I won't always be able to find the min and max of the Euclidean distance of the dataset before plotting but would still like a maximal colour range for viewers.
What alternative ways might this problem be addressed to provide acceptable contrast and color range for the `ColorFunction`?

[image: ListPlot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's better to manually construct the plot you want, while exploiting `Rescale[]`'s automatic scaling for lists?

```
data = {{0.993039, 0.0135508, 1.8244}, {0.993039, 0.0134245, 1.8244},
        {0.663126, 0.0134361, 1.79733}, {0.497758, 0.0146057, 1.77602},
        {0.497758, 0.014195, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.014113, 1.77602},
        {0.497758, 0.0140746, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0139925, 1.77602},
        {0.497758, 0.0139491, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0139141, 1.77602},
        {0.497758, 0.0138091, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.013683, 1.77602},
        {0.497758, 0.01359, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0135753, 1.77602},
        {0.497758, 0.0135056, 1.77602}, {0.497758, 0.0134964, 1.77602},
        {0.497758, 0.0147068, 1.76709}, {0.497758, 0.0144276, 1.76709},
        {0.497758, 0.0144274, 1.76709}, {0.497758, 0.014408, 1.76709},
        {0.497758, 0.0135405, 1.76709}, {0.497758, 0.0142663, 1.76083},
        {0.497758, 0.0141228, 1.76083}, {0.497758, 0.0140877, 1.76083},
        {0.398405, 0.0148334, 1.74231}, {0.398405, 0.0145646, 1.74231},
        {0.398405, 0.0139414, 1.74231}, {0.398405, 0.0149173, 1.73337},
        {0.332114, 0.0151498, 1.72431}, {0.332114, 0.0145874, 1.72431}};

Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[4],
            Transpose[{ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"] /@
                       Rescale[Norm /@ data], Point /@ data}]},
           Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}]
```

[image: plot with color scaling]